# '020-06-08 17:11:02+00:00' I want to extract the date from this time format in Python using datetime

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, type-conversion

This is what I have

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-06-08 17:11:02+00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f')
d= date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach. Since you need only the date I have stripped `:00` from the original date string.

**Demo:**

```
import datetime

sData = '2020-06-08 17:11:02+00:00'

date = datetime.datetime.strptime(sData[:-3], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+%f')
d = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-08
```

Comment: What if i want to convert the same value  '2020-06-08 17:11:02+00:00' from timestamp to a string ?

Comment: you can use `.strftime()` to convert datetime object to string